# How to debug django web application using specific port & localhost in visual studio code?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I want to debug django web application using visual code for that I have found solution that I have to edit launch.json for debugging django web application.

**launch.json**

```
"name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\web_app_test\\manage.py",
            "port": "8005",
            "address" : "192.168.1.195",
```

I have implemented above code in launch.json but still I am not able to start my web application on above port it automatically running on default port & localhost.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes I am able to debug it finally using below code after lots of search on google.

we have to define them into args using ipaddress & port.

```
"args": [
                "runserver",
                "--noreload",
                "192.168.1.195:8005",
            ],
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using `0.0.0.0`? that will map it to your local IP, and you will be able to access it within your network if you know your IP.

Comment: your answer is look like a comment.

Comment: @BearBrown, haha I'm sorry it is very early in the morning

Comment: @Mayank What error message are you getting? When you click green play button do you see any commands being executed in the terminal?